# Climate Change May Be Causing **Smaller** American Birds

Tags: grammar

This is the name of the article:

> "Study: Climate Change May Be Causing **Smaller** American Birds."

What means: Climate change could reduce the size of American birds. I can not understand why comparative adjective **Smaller** means - reduce the size of.
Is it question of grammar or style or collocation "Causing Smaller"

Comment: *Climate Change May Be Causing **greater** anxiety among the general public.* As with your example, the *comparative* adjective implies ***smaller** than American birds were before, **more anxious** than the general public were before*. It would be quite reasonable to just use the "plain" adjective for my example, but with your exact example that wouldn't make much sense (*some* American birds were always relatively small before the boffins thought up this latest scare story, so the actual meaning is *birds smaller than they used to be*, not *more instances of preexisting "small" bird types).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context "smaller" implies "*smaller than before*".  It is not that climate change is favouring small birds (like sparrows). Instead it is benefitting birds that are smaller than others in the same species and so there is evolutionary pressure which is causing the average size of birds to reduce over time.